# How to show http response code in slack alert while using prometheus, blackbox exporter and alertmanager

Tags: prometheus, slack, prometheus-alertmanager, prometheus-blackbox-exporter

I want to get the HTTP response code when the alert is triggered on slack on failure as currently i am getting many of them.

alert.rules.yml

```yaml
groups:
  - name: alert.rules
    rules:
      - alert: service_down
        expr: probe_success == 0
        for: 1m
        labels:
          severity: 3
          threshold: danger
        annotations:
          summary: "Instance *{{ $labels.instance }}* down."
          description: "*{{ $labels.instance }}* of job *{{ $labels.job }}* is down"
```

Is there a way to get the response code as well ?

Answer (score 0):

This suits my requirement now. I can get the response code using `{{ $value }}`

```yaml
groups:
  - name: alert.rules
    rules:
      - alert: service_down
        expr: (probe_http_status_code - 0) != 200
        for: 1m
        labels:
          severity: 3
          threshold: danger
        annotations:
          summary: "HTTP Response Code : {{ $value }} for URL *{{ $labels.instance }}*."
          description: "*{{ $labels.instance }}* of job *{{ $labels.job }}* is down"
```